# How to test for 'use' *failure*?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, exception

[Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/~exodist/Test-Simple-1.001006/lib/Test/More.pm) provides the commonly-used `use_ok` test to test that a module loads properly.  But how do I test that a module *fails* to load?  [Test::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Exception-0.32/lib/Test/Exception.pm) offers `dies_ok` and cousins for similar failures, but not at use-time.

This is useful when a module requires specific parameters or a specific environment to load properly, and I want to test for these conditions. As an example, perhaps my 'Foo' module requires a configuration parameter, and should fail to load otherwise:

```
use Foo 'eat my hat';  # This should work
use Foo; # This should die
```

I can easily test the first case with Test::More:

```
BEGIN { use_ok('Foo','eat my hat') }
```

But how can I test the other?

```
BEGIN { use_not_ok('Foo') }  # use_not_ok doesn't exist
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea. You sure you don't want `use Foo;` to be the same as `use Foo ();`?

Comment: In my case, I'm passing a file name as an argument to the module, and if the filename is not specified, it should die, or if the file doesn't exist, it should die, or even if the file contains invalid content, it should die.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that's a good idea. `use Foo ();` simply loads your module. Why doesn't `use Foo;`?

Comment: @ikegami: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're saying, but 'use Foo ()' fails in my case as well...

Comment: If that's true, then so does `use Foo 'eat my hat';`

Comment: @ikegami: No, becuase my `import` method looks for `eat my hat` and doesn't die in that case.

Comment: It dies before calling the `import`, according to you. (`use Foo ();` doesn't call `import`, just `require`.)

Comment: @ikegami: I don't follow. Maybe I didn't say something as clearly as I could have... but I don't think I said that.

Comment: You said `use Foo ();` dies. That means `BEGIN { require Foo }` dies. That means `BEGIN { require Foo; import Foo 'eat my hat'; }` dies. That means `use Foo 'eat my hat';` dies. So which statement is correct? 1) `use Foo ();` dies, or 2) `use Foo 'eat my hat';` doesn't die.

Comment: (You got real problems if `use Foo ();` dies.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Foo;
```

is

```
BEGIN { require Foo; import Foo; }
```

so

```
BEGIN { ok(!eval { require Foo; import Foo; 1 }); }
```

But I'd just go with

```
BEGIN { ok(!eval('use Foo; 1')); }
```

Comment: That answers my question. I wonder if it might be possible to expand the solution, though, to also allow me to catch the error thrown? i.e. if the module can die with different output, can I test that it's dying properly?

Comment: The message is placed in `$@`. Do with it as you please.